# EISDIR when trying to copy database from assets-folder to database folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to copy my database from assets-folder to the database folder but it is not working because I get an EISDIR-Error. I also tryed a lot of different solutions from stackoverflow but I had no success:

1. In the activity which is called after launching (MainMenu.java) the app I create an object of my DBHelper (SQLiteConnect.java):

   ```
   SQLiteConnect db = new SQLiteConnect(this);
   ```
2. The Constructor of the SQLiteConnect class (which extends SQLiteOpenHelper) is doing the following:

   ```
   public SQLiteConnect(Context ccontext) {
       super(ccontext, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       this.context = ccontext;
       this.dbFile = "database.sqlite";
       this.dbPath = this.context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases/";
       copyDataBase();     
   }
   ```
3. The copyDataBase() method looks like this:

   ```
   public void copyDataBase() {
       System.out.println("Debuglog: Start Database Copy");

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       OutputStream myOutput = null;
       int length;
       InputStream myInput = null;
       try
       {
           myInput =this.context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
           String file = this.dbPath + this.dbFile;        
           myOutput =new FileOutputStream(file);
           while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
           {
               myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
           }
           myOutput.close();
           myOutput.flush();
           myInput.close();
           System.out.println("Debuglog: Database Copy Finished");        
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Debuglog: Database Copy FAILED!");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

When initializing the OutputStream-object, I get the following error:

```
    10-28 21:39:12.811: W/System.err(16917): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.wwi12ama.szbeta/files/databases/database.sqlite: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Please ask if you need further information. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a question... Don't you use Java 7? If yes, why don't you use the java.nio.file API?

Comment: I use Android SDK and java.nio.file API is not available for it.